# Failed precondition: Table not initialized. on deployed universal sentence encoder from aws sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, word-embedding, amazon-sagemaker, tensorflow-hub

I have deployed a the universal_sentence_encoder_large_3 to an aws sagemaker.  When I am attempting to predict with the deployed model I get `Failed precondition: Table not initialized.` as an error. I have included the part where I save my model below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import numpy as np
def tfhub_to_savedmodel(model_name, export_path):

    model_path = '{}/{}/00000001'.format(export_path, model_name)
    tfhub_uri = 'http://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/3'

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        module = hub.Module(tfhub_uri)
        sess.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.tables_initializer()])
        input_params = module.get_input_info_dict()
        dtype = input_params['text'].dtype
        shape = input_params['text'].get_shape()

        # define the model inputs
        inputs = {'text': tf.placeholder(dtype, shape, 'text')}
        output = module(inputs['text'])
        outputs = {
            'vector': output,
        }

        # export the model
        tf.saved_model.simple_save(
            sess,
            model_path,
            inputs=inputs,
            outputs=outputs)  

    return model_path
```

I have seen other people ask this problem but no solution has been ever posted.  It seems to be a common problem with tensorflow_hub sentence encoders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running into this exact issue earlier this week while trying to modify this example [Sagemaker notebook](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-python-sdk/tensorflow_serving_container/tensorflow_serving_container.ipynb). Particularly the part where serving the model. That is, running `predictor.predict()` on the Sagemaker Tensorflow Estimator.

The solution outlined in the issue worked perfectly for me- https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/issues/773#issuecomment-509433290

I think it's just because `tf.tables_initializer()` only runs for training but it needs to be specified through the `legacy_init_op` if you want to run it during prediction.